# Unable to connect to database error when implementing try / except statement in python

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a python script below that attempts to make a connection to a sql db. The database was having some issues and I want the script to try to reconnect to the db so I added try / except. Now however I get the error message of "Unable to connect to database". If I take out the try / except statement the script works perfectly. If anyone can help me with getting the try / except statement working I would greatly appreciate it!

**Updated code with connection inside of Try**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

#conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
#cursor = conn.cursor()

def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        unique_domains = ''
        while True:
            try:
                for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                    print(domain_name)
                    domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                    cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate)$
                    FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                    c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                    lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                    unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                    pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                    outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                    with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                            outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                    break
            except:
                pass
                #print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: `except:` alone is very bad practice. exception can be anything. replace `except:` by `except Exception as e:` and print the exception

Comment: change `except:` to `except Exception as error:` and then on the following line `print(str(error))` and see why it blows up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for your reply! I replaced except with "except Exception as e:" and I printed the exception and here is what I get "<type 'exceptions.Exception'>" 

Do you have any idea of how to fix this? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @sniperd I figured out my error, not I got my script working up until 149 queries and then the process gets killed. How do I get the process to continue reconnecting to the sql db even after it gets killed.

Comment: you probably want to put a `sleep` command in so it pauses between each connection for a few seconds.  The DBA might have code that kills anything that appears to be hammering the database.

Comment: @sniperd Thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying different time delays and it has failed at least once with a 1 second delay. In case the time delay does not work, do you know if there is a way reconnect to the sql db automatically by setting it up inside the python code?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Do you know if there is a way reconnect to the sql db automatically by setting it up inside the python code?

Comment: move your `conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
cursor = conn.cursor()`  into the `try`  if that works let me know and I'll write that up as an answer :)

Comment: @sniperd Thank you for your help! Yes, moving that code into the try works. I would greatly appreciate it if you could write-up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a few things:

move this code:

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST)) 
 cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Into your `try`, that way when it loops if it dies it will remake the connection.
Like this:

```
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST)) 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
            print(domain_name)
            domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()
```

I would toss a pause between connections.  Your DBA might have code to detect too many connections in a period of time, like this:

```
#at the top of your code
import time

#in your loop add:
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did add a sleep delay and unfortunately I'm getting the same error. I moved the connection code to the two lines directly below try and it's still resulting in the same error. Is that the correct place to put them?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried the updated code for the try statement and I still get the same error. Do you have any idea of how to fix this issue?

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help! Do you have any advice on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you update your code in the question after moving your connection into the `try` block? maybe I'll see something

Comment: Thank you for your response! I updated my code in in the question block. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Take a look at my answer, see how the `conn` and `cursor` are inside the `try` block? Do that.

Comment: I apologize, I had that originally and I accidentally pasted the wrong code. I updated the code I posted with the connection inside the try block. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Change your `except` to something like this: `except Exception as error:` and then on the following `line print(str(error))`  what error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just added those statements. However, I'm not getting an error message currently. My issue is that my query is being killed by the sql server after roughly 149 queries, and I want my script to automatically reconnect and continue querying. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I would recommend one of a few things then.  Either do 100 queries and then pause for a number of minutes, or if you can detect that error to have it wait then then retry.